# Why is the WorkingSet of a process increasing and what to do about it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

During fixing problems with memory leaks in an application, I discovered another phenomenon, that I am worried about. When a large amount of objects is allocated and freed on the heap (new and delete) repeatedly, the working set of the process seems to keep increasing with every loop. I made an example using MS Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

This is the function I use to show the working set size:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

size_t getWorkingSetInBytes()
{
  size_t result = 0;

  long   lProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();

  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
    FALSE,
    lProcessId);

  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS memoryInfo;
  GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &memoryInfo, sizeof(memoryInfo));
  result = size_t(memoryInfo.WorkingSetSize);

  CloseHandle(hProcess);

  return result;
}
```

I have a simple example class:

```
class A
{
public:
  long m_one;
  long m_two;
};
```

A function to use new/delete:

```
void loopWithNew(size_t loops, size_t objects)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
  {
    {
      std::vector<A*> vecA;

      for(size_t j = 0; j < objects; ++j)
      {
        A* a = apsnew A();
        a->m_one = 42;
        a->m_two = 43;
        vecA.push_back(a);
      }

      for(auto iter = vecA.begin(); iter != vecA.end(); ++iter)
      {
        delete *iter;
      }
    }

    std::cout << "working set in bytes after deleting all objects: " << getWorkingSetInBytes() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

One to not use new/delete:

```
void loopWithoutNew(size_t loops, size_t objects)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
  {
    {
      std::vector<A> vecA(objects);

      for(size_t j = 0; j < objects; ++j)
      {
        vecA[j].m_one = 42;
        vecA[j].m_two = 43;
      }
    }

    std::cout << "working set in bytes after deleting all objects: " << getWorkingSetInBytes() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and main to call from:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  size_t loops = 10;
  size_t objects = 10000000;

  size_t beforeStart = getWorkingSetInBytes();
  std::cout << "working set before start: " << beforeStart << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl << "loops with new: " << std::endl;
  loopWithNew(loops, objects);


  std::cout << std::endl << "loops without new: " << std::endl;
  loopWithoutNew(loops, objects);
}
```

The program produces the following output:

```
working set before start: 2396160

loops with new:
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3923968
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3813376
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3964928
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3866624
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3923968
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 3989504
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4059136
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4067328
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4210688
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840

loops without new:
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
working set in bytes after deleting all objects: 4259840
```

While the loop with new/delete increases the working set over time, the version without new/delete does not seem to increase the working set. This brings up multiple related questions:

- Is this problem a symptom of heap fragmentation?
- What are the implications of this for long running processes?
- Will the process use more and more and eventually run out of memory, even if I correctly delete all objects?
- Is there a way to really 'clean-up' memory after I am done with a collection of objects or to avoid the problem? (other than allocating a pool of contiguous memory to manage for my objects manually)

Comment: Not an answer, but you can use `GetCurrentProcess` to get a (pseudo) handle to the current process instead of using `OpenProcess` with the current PID.